# ¿Como acceder a el valor de una variable $POST desde una clase?

Tags: php

Muy buenas noches caballeros, la siguiente inquietud mia es como puedo acceder al valor de una variable ya sea $_GET, $_POST, o cualquier otra variable global de php pero desde una clase o metodo que desea capturarlas.

Me explico:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Ejemplo de inicio de sesion</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />

</head> 
<body>
<form action="includes/Validar.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario" name="username"><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" name="password"> 
<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Tengo el anterior formulario sencillo pero quiero hacer una validación de esa información enviándole digamos a una clase llamada Validar.php

```
introducir el código aquí
<?php
namespace includes;
class Validaciones{
public function validarNombre()
{
    $datos = $_POST;
    return $datos;
}
public function ValidarTipo()
{
    $tipo = $_POST;
    return $tipo;   
}
}
```

Algo así que logre capturar dentro de mis métodos los valores de $POST sin tener que instanciarlos en algun lugar para poder mandarlos llamando al método?

Comment: Estás planteando el asunto justo al revés. Debes recibir los datos **fuera de la clase**, crear una instancia de la clase y pasarle los datos a la clase vía cualquiera de sus métodos. Una clase es como un molde al que hay que echarle el material para que haga aquello para lo que está programada, no sé si me entiendes. Por ejemplo, un método para validar debe recibir desde fuera la información que tiene que validar, si le pones dentro la información ese método solo sirve para validar esa información que ya le pusiste dentro, es un método capado, que no sirve para validar otro dato.

Comment: El codigo debe no estar llegando a la clase o a la instancia de la clase, en php no es necesario pasarle los parametros  a un metodo si hace uso de $_POST, la razon de eso es que es una superglobal, está disponible desde cualquier lugar de la ejecucion. Revisa donde creas la instancia de la clase, es decir donde creas new Validaciones();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás planteando el asunto justo al revés. El proceso normal sería:

1. Recibir los datos **fuera de la clase**
2. **Crear una instancia de la clase** y pasarle los datos a **esa instancia de la clase que has creado** vía cualquiera de sus métodos (o del constructor según el caso) para que la *instancia*  de la clase trabaje con esos datos y devuelva los resultados. Ampliando el concepto, la clase puede recibir no solamente datos simples como cadenas o números, puede recibir arrays, puede recibir otros objetos como instancias de otras clases con datos, etc.

Una clase es como un molde al que hay que echarle el material para que haga aquello para lo que está programada, no sé si me entiendes. ¿Te imaginas un molde con el material para fabricar una pieza fijo, inamovible? ¡Ese molde sólo serviría para fabricar esa sola pieza, no decenas, cientos, miles o millones de piezas! Más aún, ¿cuando el molde fabrique la pieza, cómo piensas sacarla para usarla? Eso es precisamente lo que ocurre ahora con los métodos de tu clase.<sup>1</sup>

Por ejemplo, un método para validar debe recibir desde fuera la información que tiene que validar (a no ser que la información sea parte de la clase porque se le pasó en el constructor al momento de crear la instancia o por medio de otro método *setter*). Si le pones dentro la información ese método solo sirve para validar esa información que ya le pusiste dentro, es un método capado, que no sirve para validar otro dato.

Veamos un ejemplo sencillo en el que recibirías por POST varios datos, entre ellos un `id` numérico. Ese valor de la pasa a `validarTipo` para que devuelva de que tipo es el dato según el valor numérico.

Si observas, `validarTipo` tiene dentro un array de tipos asociados a cada número. Si el número que se le pasa está en algunas de las claves del array te devuelve la descripción (cadena) del tipo. Si no está el valor te devuelve `Default`. Esto es sólo un ejemplo para que puedas comprender el *quid* de la cuestión.

Esta sería la clase, más o menos:

```
class Validaciones{
    public function validarNombre($datos)
    {
        //Usar datos
        //return resultado de la validación
    }
    public function validarTipo($id)
    {
        $allTypes=array(0=>"Default", 1=>"Tipo1", 2=>"Tipo2");
        $tipo=( !empty($allTypes[$id]) ) ? $allTypes[$id] : $allTypes[0];
        return $tipo;   
    }
}
```

Y este código se podría usar en infinidad de sitios en tu aplicación, en cualquier parte que se requiera validar algo. No es el archivo de la clase, es un archivo cualquiera que instancia la clase para servirse de sus métodos.

```
#VARIAS PRUEBAS ...

#Archivo que recibe el POST, un archivo cualquiera fuera de la clase
#Un $_POST simulado para fines de prueba
$_POST=array("id"=>1, "nombre"=>"Pedro"); 

#Creamos una instancia de la clase
$mValidator=new Validaciones();

#Validamos el tipo
$mType=$mValidator->validarTipo($_POST["id"]);
echo $mType.PHP_EOL;

#Otro POST, en otro momento u otro día
$_POST=array("id"=>2, "nombre"=>"María"); 
$mType=$mValidator->validarTipo($_POST["id"]);
echo $mType.PHP_EOL;

#Otro POST, en otro momento u otro día
$_POST=array("id"=>NULL, "nombre"=>"María"); 
$mType=$mValidator->validarTipo($_POST["id"]);
echo $mType.PHP_EOL;
```

En el ejemplo, hemos usado la misma clase en **tres contextos diferentes**. En cada uno de ellos le pasamos el valor al método para que este haga su trabajo, que es *decirnos de que tipo es un valor numérico dado*.

La salida por pantalla en cada caso será:

```
Tipo1
Tipo2
Default
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

---

<sup>**Notas:**</sup>

1. No digo que esto tenga que ser así siempre: que todos los métodos de todas las clases deben recibir un dato desde fuera para trabajar con él. Una `clase` es un concepto mucho más amplio. Pero para el caso que expones (un método que debe validar algo), el método debe recibir el dato desde fuera, o tomarlo de algún miembro de la clase. Y en cuanto al POST, no tiene ningún sentido intentar capturar un POST dentro de un clase, eso es pensar la clase como un archivo cualquiera, cuando no lo es.

Comment: $_POST es una superglobal, no es necesario pasarla como argumento a los métodos, si se crea una instancia de la clase debe poderse ver la variable desde la instancia. Entiendo que tu respuesta se base en buenas prácticas de desarrollo.

Comment: @Redtiens no importa que sea una super global. Una clase es un *envoltorio* ¿cómo vas a meter dentro la super global si no es a través de una instancia/método de la misma? No se puede. Y aunque se pudiera, hacer eso sería limitarla. Es muy probable que esa clase no vaya a trabajar **simpre** con valores que vengan de un `$_POST`, esa clase seguramente necesitará trabajar a veces con datos normales que vengan por ejemplo de una base de datos. ¿Qué sentido tendría en ese caso un manejo se super globales dentro? No sé si llegas a ver la diferencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder a mis inquietudes.